# Why the field description of my django model is not null?

Tags: django, django-models

I have created a model like this,

```
class fleets(models.Model):
    fleet_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    fleet_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)
```

And when I observe in the postgresql admin the table I see is like what I want,

- fleet_id as pk and not null
- fleet_name not null
- description null

[image]

But, why when I want to add some fleet with the `django-admin` it says is not possible? I forget some parameter?

[image]

Thank you very much!!

Comment: If you want to make description optional you can set it like: `description = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, required=False)` and if you want to make default it to Null you can set it by `description = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, required=False, default=Null)` @LIeims

Comment: I'm having this error, `unexpected keyword argument 'required'` :S

Comment: sorry, my bad! just try this: `description = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)` @LIeims

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding a field to your model and specifying `null=True` you are saying that field can be null. For `fleet_id`and `fleet_name`, these cannot be null since you have not specified `null=True` so they are `Not Null`.

For the django-admin, the docs specify to avoid `null=True` on `CharField`. What you want here is `blank=True` instead of `null=True`.

See the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#null).

Comment: I'm not asking this, I'm asking why if I specify description as `null=True`, why It force me to write something.

Comment: I have updated the answer to explain. Be sure to check the documentation linked for a full reason as to why its not possible. @Lleims

Answer (score 0):

```
models.CharField(blank=True) # No problem, blank is stored as ''
```

models.CharField(null=True) # NULL allowed, but will never be set as NULL